# Custom script to clean input including the following functions strip_tags() strip_html_tags() trim() passes tests even though they truly fail

Tags: php, trim, strip-tags

I am creating a validation script which is way more advanced than this little section, I am just printing the specific part I am having issues with.

The script simply takes in a single dimensional array with a list of settings, performs required tests and spits out a multidimensional array with the required string, all clean free of badness.

For some reason the `trim()` `strip_tags()` `strip_html_tags()` functions are working but failing at the same time. By this I mean the string is passed through the functions and showing as clean but the built-in PHP functions aren't working as expected.

The question is do the built in functions only work on text that is directly output to the user or should the functions work pre output ie as it is being output not while being stored in a database?

I'm looking to strip all script tags as the user inputs so I only have the plain text.

I was wanting to use a switch with each statement which I have the functions below are snippets from switch statements.

What I am trying to use which doesn't work as expected.

```
function check_input1($input)
{
    if(trim($input))
    {
        $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'CLEAN';
    }else
        $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'DIRTY';
}


function check_input2($input)
{
    if(strip_tags($input))
    {
       $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'CLEAN';
    }else
       $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'DIRTY';
}



function check_input3($input)
{
    if(strip_html_tags($input))
    {
       $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'CLEAN';
    }else
       $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'DIRTY';
}
```

What I know works directly output in html elements.

```
strip_tags(trim($key))
strip_tags(trim($value))
```

Comment: You should get into the habit of checking the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). The **Return Values** section is of particular value in this case.

Comment: Note that you're also going about this the wrong way. You should accept any and all tags and simply escape them with [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when you later output the strings back onto the page.

Comment: No Im not happy with the accept all method, I want only text in my database...accepting all isn't an option...I want to know there is only text in my database no tags...to allow tags in my database is definitely not an option. I want validation both ways. 1. as the data comes in and 2. as it is displayed to the user so there is a two way checking system in case one fails.

Comment: I have been reading the documentation, it was pretty late when I had posted so I may have misread the documentation...but thanks :D

Comment: Tags are just text. Either way you **need** to escape strings as you output them, so it makes *zero* sense to strip tags this way. If somebody enters `<sarcasm>Yea, right</sarcasm>` into a text box, they're obviously not trying to inject HTML tags. They expect your app to accept the strings as text, store them, and render them as the user typed them. Using your method, you're *changing what the user types* into something they *didn't type*, for over-zealous *false* security.

Comment: I have a degree in ethical hacking and security system design, there is no such thing as "over-zealous false security". If someone is typing script tags into my input boxes they shouldn't be. They have no need to on my site, text and numbers only, full stop and comma...thats it. thats all they need to send a message on my site :D deny all then add what is needed...thats the mind frame :D

Comment: I will then create a language that allows the user to use bold italic etc custom smiley faces etc...

Comment: first rule DENY ALL then ALLOW specific rules like maintaining a firewall...

Comment: You're missing the point. It doesn't matter how must sanitization you do on *input*, you still have to encode your strings on *output*, and it's the encode-on-output that provides *any* security. There is *no gain* for stripping tags on input.

Comment: I have never seen anyone write <sarcasm>Yea, right</sarcasm> apart from you...the sites I hang around on are exploiting input validation...I can output with removed tags...but I want a fail safe method to remove all script tags ie script does a $_GET or $_POST to a .php script. First thing before anything else the input should be stripped clean of any waste material...then the string can be worked on...

Comment: You have a degree in "ethical hacking"? I have two decades of experience in real-world application design and *security fanaticism*. I'm am *telling you*, you are going about this the wrong way. You are adding literally no additional "security" by stripping tags on input. **One hundred percent** of the security comes from **encoding the tags on output**. Using pseudo-tags like `<sarcasm>` or `<spoiler>` is extremely common in tech-oriented English-speaking websites.

Comment: And there absolutely is such a thing as over-zealous false security. It's what happens when you begin blinding applying redundant or ineffective attempts to secure something, when in fact you're adding nothing but complexity to a system. You have reached this point.

Comment: Agree to disagree :D 1. you don't know what type of site I'm creating 2. I have just under 2 decades of experience in many different subjects including nuclear weapons systems therefore we are looking from two different perspectives.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, I am saying I disagree with your perspective. Who said it was a techi speaking website? You are jumping to conclusions, may I see an example of your creations before making anymore judgement please.

Comment: As for "You are adding literally no additional "security" by stripping tags on input" I disagree, if I strip everything as it comes in then I can manipulate anyway I choose...I do not doubt your credentials in fact I'm impressed...answer me this...why would a Ethical Hacking group set up a framework written in PHP for input validation load all input into a cage, destroy the old input variable then run tests on the caged variable if it wasn't important?

Comment: I struggle to see your logic by allowing everything into a database when it could be dirty, what happens if you miss something on output, the dirty input will be output as is...potentially putting users and your site at risk.

Comment: A firewall between input and output makes much more sense that a one sided security system. If I have a security layer between all input and all output then data has to pass through the firewall on input and output minimizing any security risk.

Comment: The way your saying is - $dirtyinput -> database -> security -> output

Comment: What im saying is - $dirtyinput -> $firewall -> database -> $firewall -> output

Comment: I may have one set of tests for all on input, some tests depending on what input it is, but only some tests depending on where it needs to be output.

Comment: so on input I may want to allow <sarcasm>right yeah</sarcasm> but I dont want to allow <<SCRIPT>alert("XSS");//<</SCRIPT>

Comment: Or any other input validation evasion https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @meagar - if OP wants to disallow any and all tags in his database then that's what he wants, I don't see what's so controversial about this. If you can't answer the question or disagree then move along. If there's any more of this then I'll just purge the comments because they aren't constructive any more. Thanks.

Comment: I've long since moved along, was only drawn back by **17** unread comments. The last thing I will say is that neither `<sarcasm>right yeah</sarcasm>` or `<<SCRIPT>alert("XSS");//<</SCRIPT>` are in any way dangerous because they are **text**. They are only dangerous when you evaluate them as **html**. This can only happen on **output** and the only protection needed is to **not evaluate them as HTML**. You do this by encoding HTML entities in your output. That is the most important part of the solution and it renders all *other* parts **completely irrelevant**. I agree to disagree.

Comment: meagar I must say after reading through my reply to you from 2 years ago that I am sorry for the way I came across...It was a difficult period of life...I hope you can forgive my tone towards you and I thank you for your information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is do the built in functions only work on text that is directly output to the user or should the functions work pre output ie as it is being output not while being stored in a database?

The functions in question work on any string. There is no different between a string destined for the database vs a string destined for stdout.

Your problem is that you seem to be expecting the functions to return true/false, as some kind of indication that they *found* something to strip. That's not how they work. They return the modified string. Every single `if` condition will enter the `CLEAN` section (assuming its function doesn't return `""`), and silently throw away the cleaned string which was returned by the function.

What you want is something like this:

```
function check_input3($input)
{
    $output = strip_html_tags($input);

    if ($output == $input) {
        // strip_html_tags didn't remove anything
        $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'CLEAN';
    } else {
        // variables differ, so strip_html_tags found something to remove
        $cleaninput[$i][$input] = 'DIRTY';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For others reference you might want to consider the inspekt php4 and 5 framework for input validation funded by OWASP code.google.com/p/inspekt/wiki/DocsAndSupport provides a firewall type scenario between the input and output...nice little tutorial here codediesel.com/php/data-filtering-and-validation-using-inspekt